# row_number() over() continuous over union select

Tags: sql, hive, union, hiveql, row-number

I am creating a table and inserting data into that table with a query1 union query2. The issue is that I want to add row_number() to the table however when I add row_number() over() to either of the queries, the numbering only applies to query1 or query2 but not to the entire table as a whole.

I did a hack to get my result where I insert the data into the table (table_no_serial) using insert query1 union query2, then I create a second table like so

```
insert into table_w_serial select row_number() over(), * from table_no_serial;
```

is it possible to get this right the first time around?

```
insert into table purchase_table 
select row_number() over(), w.ts, w.tail, w.event, w.action, w.msg, w.tags 
from table1 w 
where 
w.action = 'stop'
union 
select row_number() over(), t.ts, t.tail, t.event, t.action, t.msg, t.tags 
from table2 t
where 
f.action = 'stop';
```

I want something like this to work.

I want to write a code where the resulting table (endtable) will be a union of the first query and the second query and will include a constant row number across both queries so that if query1 returns 50 results and query2 returns 40 results. End table will have row number from 1-90

Comment: Try constructing a surrounding query with row_number, on top of union. ie `select row_rumber(), col1, col2 from ( select col1...from tbl union select col1...from tbl2)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
insert into table purchase_table ( . . . ) -- include column names here
    select row_number() over (), ts, tail, event, action, msg, tags
    from ((select w.ts, w.tail, w.event, w.action, w.msg, w.tags 
           from table1 w 
           where w.action = 'stop'
          ) union all 
          (select w.ts, w.tail, w.event, w.action, w.msg, w.tags 
           from table2 w
           where f.action = 'stop'
          )
         ) w;
```

Note that this also changes `union` to `union all`.  `union all` is more efficient; only use `union` if you want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: Gordon please take a look at my code above again (editted). The names of the columns are the same in the two tables. Will your answer still be valid?

Comment: @HarryBarsegyan . . . There is not reason as far as I know to use a temporary table, but it is a viable solution.

Comment: gordon table1 and table2 are two different tables

Comment: @HarryBarsegyan . . . So what?  The `union all` brings them together.

Comment: I tried doing this however I am getting an error "failed to recognize predicate union" ...where you say --include column names here, we put the column names of purchase table or all columns from both tables? also in the statement select row_number() over(), ts, tail, event.... do we need to specify which table these variables are from? how would the select statement know which table for example tail is from